# Is there a way to "override" a jaxrs resource?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I have to use a library which provides a jaxrs rest-api for some task. This api is a class implementing an jaxrs annotated interface. Now I have the requirement to build a "wrapper" around one of those endpoints, because some server side checks are required before the access to those resources.

The only working way I found to accomplish this is to disallow the access to those resources completely, add a new resources at a new path and call the original resource via a server-side "rest proxy". Is there any nicer way to do that? I hoped maybe there would be a way to "override" this resource somehow, but I could not find anything anywhere. I also read about sub-resource locators but this did not work since the locator seems to be ignored even at the root path, if there is a matching resource underneath annotated with the full path.

I am using Resteasy.
What is the best practice to accomplish this?

Comment: which jax-rs impl do you use? Try to disable class path scanning for provider/path annotations or exclude the specific package

Comment: I edited my question, I am using resteasy. I will try your suggestion, thank you.

Comment: Are filters not good enough?

Comment: I am actually quite new to jaxrs and did not know about that feature. It sounds like it should do what I want in a more elegant way. I will try that out, thanks

Comment: If you just need to use the filter for some classes, register the filter using a [DynamicFeature](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9956)

Comment: well if any, I would use a pre matching filter which cannot be registered dynamically if I understood correctly. (I mean, what would that even do?)